# tubo nextjs vscode breakpoints not hitting for server

Tags: visual-studio-code, next.js, turbo

Turbo nextjs breakpoints not being hit when I run the debug configuration in the nextjs documenation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ultimately worked was:

Added this to my `package.json`:

```
    "dev": "NODE_OPTIONS=\"--inspect=9234\" next dev",
```

```
pnpm dev
```

Then the server starts and sends this message:

```
- info the --inspect option was detected, the Next.js server for pages should be inspected at port 9236.
```

And then I added this to my `launch.json` using the port number specified.

```
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Attach Backend 4",
      "address": "localhost",
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "port": 9236
    },
```

Then I ran the configuration and it worked.